# Arrays (driver’s exam scorer)

Tags: c++

I am working on this assignment and I am pretty new to c++, we are working with arrays, and I am having trouble reading inputs from a file.

What I need to do is create a program that will read inputs from a file which is a driver's exam score, and the program should tell if the person pass or fail, how many answers were right and wrong, and which ones were the wrong answers, this is what I have so far.

My compiler tells me there is no erros but when I run it, it just ask for the file, but nothing prints if i enter a file that doens't exists it will report it and quit, but when I put the right one it just do nothing, i tried using (&) to pass variables but it gives me erros, also my teacher wants me to pass information using arguments

if you can spot any other problems please let me know i will apreciated the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void check(char[], char[], int, int);

int main()
{
  // number of questions
  const int  questions = 20;
  // the user need 15 right answers to pass
  const int correct = 15;
  // this is the order of the right answers
  char answer[questions] = {
    'B','D','A','A','C',
    'A','B','A','C','D',
    'B','C','D','A','D',
    'C','C','B','D','A'
  };

  // this is to store the answer in a file into this variable
  char user_input[questions];

  // I need to ask for the name of the file.
  ifstream file;
  string file_name;

  cout << "Enter the file name: ";
  cin >> file_name;
  file.open(file_name);

  // if file name doesn's exist
  if (!file)
    {
      cout << "The file is not open!!" << endl;

      // here i am trying to get input from the file
      while(file >> user_input)
        {
          check(answer, user_input, questions, correct);
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
void check(char answer[], char user_input[], int questions, int correct)
{
  int counter = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < questions; i++)
    {
      if(answer[i] == user_input[i]);
      counter++;
    }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Pass/Fail  " << "#correct  " << "#incorrect  " << "wrong answers" << endl;
  cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
  if (counter >= correct)
    {
      cout << "pass" << endl;
    }else{cout << "fail" << endl;}
}
```

this is how the file looks like.

```
B B A A C B B A D C B C D A D C C B B C
B D A A C A B A C D B C D A D C C B D A
B B A A C C B A C D B C D A C C C B D A
A B A A C A A A C C B C D A C C C B D A
A B C D A B C D A B C D A B C D A B C D
B D A A C A A A C D B C D A D C C B D A
B D A A C A B A D C B C D A D C C B D A
```

here is more information about my assignment
[https://kuvapcsitrd01.kutztown.edu/~carelli/website/courses/csc135/Assignments/p6-arrays.pdf](https://kuvapcsitrd01.kutztown.edu/%7Ecarelli/website/courses/csc135/Assignments/p6-arrays.pdf)

Comment: No errors is a good sign, but [your compile can also offer warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/7P1MKah5T)  Would you agree with the warning described at that link?

Comment: Note that compiler's suggestion is based on the assumption that you may not have made a mistake and want the behaviour the code describes. The main point is look at the code pointed out by the compiler and ask your self, "Do I really mean this?"

Comment: @DrewDormann I don't get any warnings neither so far it is a good sign but I want to believe the problem is that I am not passing any information because it doesn't print anything I try to use "getline" to print the file in the function called "check" and it did nothing, so I want to say that I am not passing any information and I can't use "&" to pass, I need to use arguments probably I can make the int main, a function called example: "read" and then make the arguments in that function to pass the information, still I don't know if it is a good idea but it is worth the try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See where you actually read the file.

You even commented the place.

And then go up the scope and see where you actually do it.

You commented that too.

I think you made a typo.

Comment: If that wasn't enough, the comments are as follow: // if file doesn't exist  { // get input }

Comment: Omg, thanks so much you were right, my error was that I had the while loop inside of the if statement that states, if the file doesn't exist which it didn't let the while loop do the work, now it is actually printing something, now I just need to fix the header and the way I need the program to print the info thanks a lot Tomáš Růžička.